# How to join and reduce two datasets with arrays?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need an idea for how to join two datasets with millions of arrays. Each dataset will have Longs numbered 1-10,000,000. But with different groupings in each one ex. [1,2] [3, 4] and [1], [2, 3], [4] output should be [1,2,3,4]
I need some way to join these sets efficiently.

I have tried an approach where I explode and group by multiple times, finally sorting and distincting the arrays. This works on small sets but is very inefficent for large sets because it explodes the number of rows many times over.

Any ideas on how to use another approach like a reducer or aggregation to solve this problem more efficiently.

The following is a scala code example. However, I would need an approach that works in java as well.

```
val rdd1 = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(Array("""{"groupings":[1,2,3]}""", """{"groupings":[4,5,6]}""", """{"groupings":[7,8,9]}""", """{"groupings":[10]}""", """{"groupings":[11]}"""))
val rdd2 = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(Array("""{"groupings":[1]}""", """{"groupings":[2,3,4]}""", """{"groupings":[7,8]}""", """{"groupings":[9]}""", """{"groupings":[10,11]}"""))
val srdd1 = spark.read.json(rdd1)
val srdd2 = spark.read.json(rdd2)

Dataset 1:
+---------+
|groupings|
+---------+
|[1, 2, 3]|
|[4, 5, 6]|
|[7, 8, 9]|
|     [10]|
|     [11]|
+---------+

Dataset 2:
+---------+
|groupings|
+---------+
|      [1]|
|[2, 3, 4]|
|   [7, 8]|
|      [9]|
| [10, 11]|
+---------+
```

Output should be

```
+------------------+
|         groupings|
+------------------+
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|
|         [7, 8, 9]|
|          [10, 11]|
+------------------+
```

Update:
This was my original code, which I had problems running, @AyanGuha had me thinking that perhaps it would be simpler to just use a series of joins instead, I am testing that now and will post a solution if it works out.

```
srdd1.union(srdd2).withColumn("temp", explode(col("groupings")))
                    .groupBy("temp")
                    .agg(collect_list("groupings").alias("groupings"))
                    .withColumn("groupings", callUDF("distinctLongArray", callUDF("flattenDistinctLongArray", col("groupings"))))
                    .withColumn("temp", explode(col("groupings")))
                    .groupBy("temp")
                    .agg(collect_list("groupings").alias("groupings"))
                    .withColumn("groupings", callUDF("distinctLongArray", callUDF("flattenDistinctLongArray", col("groupings"))))
                    .withColumn("temp", explode(col("groupings")))
                    .groupBy("temp")
                    .agg(collect_list("groupings").alias("groupings"))
                    .withColumn("groupings", callUDF("distinctLongArray", callUDF("flattenDistinctLongArray", col("groupings"))))
                    .select(callUDF("sortLongArray", col("groupings")).alias("groupings"))
                    .distinct()
```

What this code showed was that after 3 iterations the data coalesced, ideally then 3 joins would do the same.

Update 2:
Looks like I have a new working version, still seems inefficient but I think this will be handled better by spark.

```
val ardd1 = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(Array("""{"groupings":[1,2,3]}""", """{"groupings":[4,5,6]}""", """{"groupings":[7,8,9]}""", """{"groupings":[10]}""", """{"groupings":[11,12]}""", """{"groupings":[13,14]}"""))
val ardd2 = spark.sparkContext.makeRDD(Array("""{"groupings":[1]}""", """{"groupings":[2,3,4]}""", """{"groupings":[7,8]}""", """{"groupings":[9]}""", """{"groupings":[10,11]}""", """{"groupings":[12,13]}""", """{"groupings":[14, 15]}"""))
var srdd1 = spark.read.json(ardd1)
var srdd2 = spark.read.json(ardd2)

val addUDF = udf((x: Seq[Long], y: Seq[Long]) => if(y == null) x else (x ++ y).distinct.sorted)
val encompassUDF = udf((x: Seq[Long], y: Seq[Long]) => if(x.size == y.size) false else (x diff y).size == 0)
val arrayContainsAndDiffUDF = udf((x: Seq[Long], y: Seq[Long]) => (x.intersect(y).size > 0) && (y diff x).size > 0)
var rdd1 = srdd1
var rdd2 = srdd2.withColumnRenamed("groupings", "groupings2")
for (i <- 1 to 3){
    rdd1 = rdd1.join(rdd2, arrayContainsAndDiffUDF(col("groupings"), col("groupings2")), "left")
        .select(addUDF(col("groupings"), col("groupings2")).alias("groupings"))
        .distinct
        .alias("rdd1")
    rdd2 = rdd1.select(col("groupings").alias("groupings2")).alias("rdd2")
}
rdd1.join(rdd2, encompassUDF(col("groupings"), col("groupings2")), "leftanti")
    .show(10, false)
```

Outputs:

```
+------------------------+
|groupings               |
+------------------------+
|[10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]|
|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]      |
|[7, 8, 9]               |
+------------------------+
```

I will try this at scale and see what I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I finally figured it out.

First of all with my array joins I was doing something very wrong, which I overlooked initially.

When joining two arrays with a equivalency. EX. does [1,2,3] equal [1,2,3]? the arrays are hashed. I was doing an intersection match using a UDF. Given x in [1,2,3] is any x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. This cannot be hashed and therefore requires a plan which will check every row with every row.

So to do this you have to explode both arrays first, then join them.
You can then apply other criteria. For example I saved time by only joining arrays which were not equal and when summed were less then the other.

Example with a self join:

```
    rdd2 = rdd2.withColumn("single", explode(col("grouping"))) // Explode the grouping
    temp = rdd2.withColumnRenamed("grouping", "grouping2").alias("temp") // Alias for self join
    rdd2 = rdd2.join(temp, rdd2.col("single").equalTo(temp.col("single")) // Compare singles which will be hashed
                                .and(col("grouping").notEqual(col("grouping2"))) // Apply further conditions
                                .and(callUDF("lessThanArray", col("grouping"), col("grouping2"))) // Make it so only [1,2,3] [4,5,6] is joined and not the duplicate [4,5,6] [1,2,3], for efficiency
                                    , "left") // Left so that the efficiency criteria do not drop rows
```

I then grouped by the grouping which was joined against aggregated the groupings from the self join.

```
rdd2.groupBy("grouping")
    .agg(callUDF("list_agg",col('grouping2')).alias('grouping2')) // List agg is a UserDefinedAggregateFunction which aggregates lists into a distinct list
    .select(callUDF("addArray", col("grouping"), col("grouping2")).alias("grouping")) // AddArray is a udf which concats and distincts 2 arrays
grouping   grouping2
[1,2,3]    [3,4,5]
[1,2,3]    [2,6,7]
[1,2,3]    [2,8,9]
becomes just
[1,2,3]    [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
after addArray
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

I then iterated that code 3 times, which seems to make everything coalesce and threw in a distinct for good measure.

Notice from the original question I had two datasets, for my specific problem I discovered some assumptions about the first and second set. The first set I could assume had no duplicates as it was a master list, the second set had duplicates hence I only needed to apply the above code to the second set, then join it with the first. I would assume if both sets had duplicates they could be unioned together first.

Answer (score 0):

> This works on small sets but is very inefficent for large sets because it explodes the number of rows many times over.

I don't think you have other options than `explode`ing the arrays, `join` followed by `distinct`. Spark is fairly good at such computations and tries doing them as much using internal binary rows as possible. The datasets are compressed and often comparisons are done at byte level (outside JVM)

That's just a matter of enough memory to hold all the elements which may not that big deal.

I'd recommend giving your solution a try and check out the physical plan and the stats. It could in the end turn out to be the only available solution.

Comment: Yes actually I should have stated that this crashed very quickly on the larger sets. When spinning up more machines it took quite a long time and still was crashed. This is not something I would want for a production system. Especially when the problem itself does not seem to be that hard, it seems like there must be a better way.

Comment: In fact, the problem is pretty hard. You have to match each record in DS1 with each record with DS2 (cartesian product), and then merge what can be merged. Also you need to do this iteratively unless everything is either fully merged or not possible to merge.

Comment: @AyanGuha it does not have to be a Cartesian product. You are able to check if a number exists between two arrays, an intersect of sorts. Which in itself is doable. But you are correct that if you go this direction it has to be iterative, as numbers can be chained together.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution using ARRAY data type that is supported as part of HiveQL. This will at least make your coding simple [i.e. building out the logic]. Code below assumes that the raw data is in a text file.

Step 1. Create table

```
create table array_table1(array_col1 array<int>)  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED 
BY'\n' STORED AS text;
```

Step 2: Load data into both tables

```
LOAD DATA INPATH('/path/to/file') OVERWRITE INTO TABLE array_table1
```

Step 3: Apply sql functions to get results

```
select distinct(explode(array_col1)) from array_table1 union 
select distinct(explode(array_col2)) from array_table2
```

I am not clear on what is the final output you are looking for, from the example. Is it just union of all distinct numbers - or are they supposed to have a grouping? But anyway, with the tables created you can use a combination of distinct, explode(), left anti join and union - to get the expected results.

You may want to optimize this code to filter the final data set again for duplicates.

Hope that helps!

Comment: So i was considering using anti joins to filter my results but i was weary of the performance hit. But i think I will give that a shot.
And to clarify the output I am basically trying to join lists when they share common numbers. Ie. if [1,2] and [2,3] they share a 2 so it should become [1, 2, 3].
Ideally this is a groupby problem where the key can be dynamic, but I don't think that is possible due to the architecture.